# How to check if a user can access a given file?

Tags: permissions, files, users, access-control

*nix user permissions are really simple, but things can get messy when you have to take in account all the parent directory access before reaching a given file. How can I check if the user has enough privileges? If not, then which directory is denying access?

For example, suppose a user `joe`, and the file `/long/path/to/file.txt`. Even if `file.txt` was chmoded to 777, joe still has to be able to access `/long/`, and then `/long/path/` and then `/long/path/to/` before. What I need is a way to automatically check this. If `joe` does not have access, I would also like to know where he has been denied. Maybe he can access `/long/`, but not `/long/path/`.

Comment: So you're question is more "how to determine why a user cannot access a file"? :)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

To verify access visually, you can use

```
namei -m /path/to/really/long/directory/with/file/in
```

which will output all of the permissions in the path in a vertical list.

or

```
namei -l /path/to/really/long/directory/with/file/in
```

to list all owners and the permissions. Other answers explain how to verify this programmatically.

Comment: This should be the right answer. In fact using `namei <path> || exit 1` allows you to detect a permission problem much easily in a script.

Comment: it doesn't answer directly whether joe has access to the file.

Comment: This also does not elucidate how access control lists might influence things.

Answer (score 23):

If you have root access, impersonate the user, then run `test -r` (read), `test -w` (write), or `test -x` (execute) to check whether the user can read/write/execute the given file.

```
sudo -u otheruser test -w /file/to/test || {
   echo "otheruser cannot write the file"
}
```

Comment: This is exact answer what I was searching for. Title of this question could be misleading.

Comment: a slight embellishment to check if a process running as "USER:GROUP" can access a given file would be the following command:
sudo su - USER -g GROUP -s /bin/bash -c "test -r /path/to/file"

Answer (score 21):

You can use bash to do this.

```
$ cat check-permissions.sh
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
# Handle non-absolute paths
if ! [[ "$file" == /* ]] ; then
    path=.
fi
dirname "$file" | tr '/' $'\n' | while read part ; do
    path="$path/$part"
    # Check for execute permissions
    if ! [[ -x "$path" ]] ; then
        echo "'$path' is blocking access."
    fi
done
if ! [[ -r "$file" ]] ; then
    echo "'$file' is not readable."
fi
$ ./check-permissions.sh /long/path/to/file.txt
```

To check this for a specific user, you can use `sudo`.

```
sudo -u joe ./check-permissions.sh /long/path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: sudo -u joe script . Here script is the name of the script file right? so your telling sudo to act like joe was calling the script?

Comment: Precisely. I have modified my answer to clarify that.

Comment: I made a slight modification to my script to handle non-absolute paths.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman With an absolute path, did you mean to initialize `path` to be empty? or `/`?

Comment: @Gilles: I meant for it to be empty. In the example, `path` is set to `/long` the first time around the loop, which is correct. Should I set `path` to nothing explicitly (`path=`)? Also, thanks for simplifying out my use of `tr`.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman I tried to test it using the following file: /root/test/test.txt (permissions are `0755`, `0700`, and `0777`). I issued `sudo -u joe ./check-permissions.sh /root/test/test.txt`, and nothing happened. Did I missed something?

Comment: @Metalcoder: An [edit last night](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/82349/5) broke it. I've reverted the changes.

Comment: btw, if file had permissions like 000, the script wouldn't tell that it is not readable.

Comment: @rush: I have added that functionality to the script.

Comment: I wonder whether it is possible to do something like that without being able to log in as `joe`. It should be possible since `groups joe` returns all groups the user belongs to.

Comment: UPVOTE/ACCEPT,  my target system doesn't have namei. Also if you check, you usually want to react. I can insert setfacl/chmod and add X to user, while checking access in one step

Answer (score 5):

As I got from your question, you should check it for different users (not only joe), so in that case the easiest way is to recursivly check it via sudo like this:

```
FILE=$1 ; T_USER=$2 ;
if sudo -u $T_USER [ -r "$FILE" ] ; then
    echo "original file $1 is readable for $T_USER"
else
    while sudo -u $T_USER [ ! -x "$FILE" ] ; do FILE=$(dirname "$FILE") ; done
    echo "only $FILE is readable for $T_USER"
fi
```

usage:

```
./script.sh /long/path/to/file.txt joe
```

Comment: Joe needs execute permissions on the directories, not read permissions.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman yes, you're right. Fixed.

Comment: @rush I tried to test it using the following file: /root/test/test.txt (permissions are `0755`, `0700`, and `0777`). I issued `./script.sh  /root/test/test.txt joe` and it echoed `original file /root/test/test.txt is readable for joe`. Also, while trying this I misstyped the test dir: `./script.sh  /root/tst/test.txt joe`, and it echoed `original file /root/tst/test.txt is readable for joe`. Did I missed something?

Comment: @Metalcoder sorry, it's my fault. There was one extra exclamation. It's removed now, you can try it one more time, it should work fine now.

Comment: @rush it worked! That extra exclamation negates the result of `-r $FILE`, right?

Comment: @Metalcoder, yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt at providing this functionality. I've opted to use `stat`, a `while` loop, and `dirname`.

I've created this script, `walkdir.bash`:

```
#/bin/bash

cwd="$1"
while [ "x$cwd" != x/ ]; do
  info=`stat "$cwd" |grep "Access: ("`
  printf "%s : %s\n" "$info" "$cwd"

  cwd=`dirname "$cwd"`;
done
```

You run it like so:

```
$ walkdir.bash "/home/saml/blog/vmware_networking_tutorial/url.txt"
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml) : /home/saml/blog/vmware_networking_tutorial/url.txt
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml) : /home/saml/blog/vmware_networking_tutorial
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml) : /home/saml/blog
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml) : /home/saml
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root) : /home
```