# Why can't I change directory to the current directory with permission denied?

Tags: files, permissions, postgresql

I am trying to restore a database with the following command:

```
$ sudo -u postgres pg_restore -C -d dvdrental dvdrental.tar 
[sudo] password for t:
```

However, I am receiving the following error message:

> could not change directory to **"/home/t/mydata/.../relation model/SQL/implementations/Implementations, i.e. relational database management systems/postgreSQL/general/web/postgresqltutorial/databases"**: Permission denied
>
> pg_restore: [archiver] could not open input file "dvdrental.tar": No such file or directory

I was wondering why I can't change directory to the current directory with permission denied?

File permission bits are:

```
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 2838016 May 26  2013 dvdrental.tar
```

Is it because one of its ancestry directory is not both readable and executable by any one?  The file has  many ancestry directories, and how can I verify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current directory, and all its parent directories, have to be accessible for the `postgres` user, *i.e.* have the executable/searchable bit set for whichever owner/group/other permission applies on each directory when determining `postgres`’s permissions, or grant that permission using ACLs.

To check the permissions, use `namei`:

```
namei -l /path/to/directory
```

See [How to check if a user can access a given file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82347/86440) for details.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a faster way to verify that there is anacestry directory without read or executable permission to anyone than manually `ls -l` every ancestry directory?

Comment: Thanks again. Is there a faster way to add read and execution permission bits for all the ancestry directories of a given file, than manually for each ancestry directory?

Comment: Also is it correct that if I have a symbolic link to a directory which doesn't have read and execution permission for anyone, making the link have read and execution permission for anyone still doesn't allow any one to traverse indirectly into the directory via the link?

Comment: I don’t think there’s a faster way to *set* the bits, because the appropriate value can depend on the directories’ ownership. Regarding symbolic links, they don’t carry permissions under Linux; a user’s ability to access a directory pointed to by a symbolic link is entirely determined by the directory’s permissions.

Comment: What do the permission bits of a symlink do?

Comment: [They don’t do anything on Linux.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/293763/86440)

Comment: If a symlink doesn't have read and execution permission for anyone, does it mean we can't access the linked file via the symlink?

Comment: **Under Linux, a symlink’s permissions don’t have any effect**, and `chmod` won’t let you change them. Under Linux, a symlink can’t *not* have read and execution permission for every one.

Comment: Thanks again.  (1) Under other *nix, where chmod can change permission bits of a symlink, If a symlink doesn't have read and execution permission for anyone, does it mean we can't access the linked file via the symlink?  (2) Under Linux, my symlinks have `lrwxrwxrwx`, so read and execution for anyone. I am confused what you mean by "Under Linux, a symlink can’t not have read and execution permission for every one".

Comment: (1) Other systems I’ve looked at (macOS and FreeBSD) allow symlink permissions to be changed, but ignore those permissions; access to a directory or file *via* a symlink is determined by the permissions of the target, not the symlink. (2) Yes, under Linux symlinks show `rwx` permissions for anyone.

Answer (score 5):

You can, user `postgres` can't.

`sudo -u postgres`  changes user-id to postgres and then runs the commands.
at now user postgres can't access the input file, or even the current directory.

Instead, do it this way:

```
$ sudo -u postgres pg_restore -C -d dvdrental < dvdrental.tar
```

This way the file is opened by your shell under your account before sudo starts and `pg_restore` then accesses the file content on standard input

Comment: Thanks. "user postgres can't access the input file, or even the current directory", how or where is this set up?

Comment: I have added permission bits of the file. The archive file is readable by anyone.

Comment: seems to be down some rabbit hole of the users home directory, user postgres needs execute permission on all the dirctories in that chain. it's easier to just use redirection instead.