# Why can't I change directory to the current directory with permission denied?

Tags: postgresql, restore

I am trying to restore a database with the following command:

```
$ sudo -u postgres pg_restore -C -d dvdrental dvdrental.tar 
[sudo] password for t:
```

However, I am receiving the following error message:

> could not change directory to **"/home/t/mydata/.../relation model/SQL/implementations/Implementations, i.e. relational database management systems/postgreSQL/general/web/postgresqltutorial/databases"**: Permission denied
>
> pg_restore: [archiver] could not open input file "dvdrental.tar": No such file or directory

I was wondering why I can't change directory to the current directory with permission denied?

File permission bits are:

```
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 t t 2838016 May 26  2013 dvdrental.tar
```

Comment: Please merge this with https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449983/why-cant-i-change-directory-to-the-current-directory-with-permission-denied#449985